# Xdebug V3 doesn't stop breakpoints in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug, xdebug-3

I am trying to debug on my XAMPP using VSCode and didn't worked. I know there are tons of questions about this and I've tried everything I can but still won't work.

There is really 1 thing weird thou about my xdebug extension.I am currently using PHP v7.4.12 and Xdebug version 3.

I know my Xdebug works on PHP because I viewed `phpinfo()` and it shows just how I set it. The weird part is among the many of the tutorials out there normally `zend_extension = path..`,`xdebug.remote_enable = 1` and `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` should be enough but when I viewed phpinfo it is as follows below:

[image]

I tried to set it with `xdebug.remote_port = 9000` and `xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"` but still won't work. I even have read about changing localhost to `127.0.0.1` but still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my launch.json file and php ini file.

**php.ini**

```ini
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch current script in console",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

If it is caused maybe due to not setting "pathMappings", anyone can teach me how to use this?

By the way the xdebug.log also doesn't work

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are using Xdebug v3 but keep using Xdebug v2 config parameters. You need to go through [Upgrading from Xdebug 2 to 3 Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and adjust your settings.

Xdebug v3 uses **different** config params than Xdebug v2 (*your `phpinfo()` output tells you exactly that on your screenshot*). 5 out of 6 "xdebug." params from your current php.ini do **nothing** in Xdebug v3.

For Xdebug 3 it should be like this (**based on your original config** -- better start using new 9003 default port):

```ini
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.log = "C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I was doing this for 2days now and still can't do it. cause of this it's now working. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you, ppa:ondrej/php changed xdebug from V2 to V3 without notice and everything was broken

Comment: change the above port to 9003 for VSCODE to work out of the box I believe.

Comment: @EricSebasta This answer is for that specific question -- especially since it says "based on your original config". I'm sure you and others do not do StackOverflow programming when something gets copied without reading what it actually does and how it can be adjusted to your particular situation. **But yes, changing the port to `9003` (or simply removing that line since it's a default port now) will be a more suitable for new setups/new users**

Comment: I understand - and I agree completely- but since lots of people will be led here for the answer, I wanted to make a note that the default for VSCODE is 9003 so simply slapping that code in vscode will fail unless they change that port number to 9003..

Comment: @EricSebasta I though about removing that line, and actually did it .. but then had to put it back. The reason is the original question -- it has `9000` there, in the VSCode config. So seeing `9000` there and assuming default or seeing actual `9003` here in Xdebug config will be more confusing for such "do not know how it all works" folks. So I will have to leave as is with old 9000 ports

Comment: I know this is off topic but don't forget SELinux can block php from connecting by default, use `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`.  (I'm setting up PHP dev after reinstalling Fedora and it's now defaulting to xdebug 3, so the above was helpful, but also needed this config tweak)

Comment: @Neek That's depends on a distro/OS used. Have not seen the mention of this for a while. Bu yes, it's a known (to me) issue that needs to be checked when you do not see any outgoing connections (Xdebug may not even try to make one). I remember it since 2014 thread... https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206339279-Xdebug-can-not-connect-to-PhpStorm-on-OS-X-Mavericks?page=1#community_comment_206899645

Comment: you the xdebug king!

Comment: I have to add "stopOnEntry":true in the launch.json file.
Thank you

Comment: I was about to go crazy

Comment: Thank you very much. now xdebug 3 has worked. Mator Skalangkog

Comment: xdebug.start_with_request = yes

Comment: IMPORTANT!! => Be sure to edit the correct `php.ini` file, or nothing will make a difference! In my case, I was struggling for 2 days editing the `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` file, when it should be `/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini`!! Credits to LazyOne in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178152/xdebug-is-ignoring-breakpoints-in-vscode-trying-to-debug-php-file

Comment: you got it. thank you for this. saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 9):

OS: Windows 10

VS Code marks the breakpoints as "unverified breakpoint".

In my case, i had to add "pathMappings":

```
"configurations": [{
    ...,
    "pathMappings": {
        "remote/path/to/webroot/": "${workspaceFolder}",
    }
}]
```

Sidenote when you are working with docker: The remote path is the path inside the docker container.