# Xdebug: Laravel & vue in XAMPP + Visual Studio Code. Breakpoints doesn´t work

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I cannot configure correctly Xdebug in Visual Studio Code for a Laravel & Vue project.

I tried with several posts in Internet about it but any works for me. I had a error about when I started with `php artisan serve` but now is corrected. My php.ini, VSCode configuration...Everything looks like correct:

[image]

But when I put several breakpoints never spot in code.

But still when I put some breakpoint

This is my PHP info output

[image]

This is my launch.json VSCode file:

[image]

And this is my php.ini

[image]

Comment: What is your PHP and Xdebug version?

Comment: **Xdebug installed: 3.0.3** in **PHP Version: 7.4.15**. The recommendation obtained in  [link](https://xdebug.org/wizard) _Wizard xDebug_

Comment: So you have Xdebug v3. Accordingly to your screenshot you are using Xdebug v2 config parameters that do almost nothing in v3. Go trough v2 to 3 upgrade guide (https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and update your config accordingly. Or find and follow some Xdebug v3 specific guide. A basic example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141934/783119

Comment: @LazyOne I got version 3. Where do you seen v2? I edit my question with php info output.  May be is for Debug Build in NO?

Comment: *"Where do you seen v2?"* On your first screenshot -- the `php.ini` file content, Xdebug config section. As I have said earlier -- v2 config parameters do NOTHING in Xdebug v3. Please update your config with the new parameter names/values.

Comment: "Debug Build: No" means nothing to Xdebug. It's for developers of PHP itself. ``--enable-debug-pack`` is for people compiling their own extensions, and also not related to debugging your PHP code.

Comment: Ok @Derick. Any idea for my problem?

Comment: I have updated my question again with php.ini and config screenshot. xDebug looks like listen. But Breakspoint doesnt work. Why?¿