# Xdebug: "Launch currently open script" works but "Listen for Xdebug" does not. Using VSCode, PHP 8.0.11, and WinNMP (nginx localhost):

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, firefox, xdebug, firefox-developer-tools

Using VSCode, when I put a breakpoint in a PHP file, start the debugger and click the Run and Debug button, debugging works as expected. Execution stops on the breakpoint and information is shown in the left side bar. But when I initiate the same process using the "Listen for Xdebug" dropdown (after creating the launch.json file as described below) and then reload the PHP file in question in my browser, the breakpoint is ignored and the webpage loads.  In the past when this was working, reloading the page would trigger debugging, but after I reinstalled VSCode and WinNMP, something has changed and I don't know what.

I installed Xdebug using https://xdebug.org/wizard, and followed the instructions:

```
Download php_xdebug-3.1.5-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll
Move the downloaded file to ext, and rename it to php_xdebug.dll
Update D:\winnmp\conf\php.ini and add the line:
zend_extension = xdebug
Restart the webserver
```

My Xdebug PHP.INI is:

```
  zend_extension = xdebug
  xdebug.mode = debug
```

I added the xdebug.mode line since that's what Xdebug instructs to get step debugging.

I deleted a prior launch.json file that was there, and For the launch.json, I clicked on Run > Add Configuration > PHP Listen for Xdebug, which generated this launch.json;

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm using Firefox Developer as my browser. Refreshing a webpage that I've opened in VSCode and with a breakpoint set has no effect on the debugging in VSCode.  I've tried launching Firefox in the CMD window:

```
"C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -start-debugger-server
```

and there is no difference.  I changed the launch.json to:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Firefox",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

and debugging isn't affected.

I've installed several Firefox extensions, in turn, Xdebug-helper, Xdebug-ext, and Zend-debugger Toolbar.  None of them had any effect.  What DID have some effect was installing the VSCode extension, Debugger for Firefox.  In the extension's options I set the Port to 9003 and entered the absolute path for firefox.exe.  After doing this, when I start the debugger, Firefox asks for permission to connect to the remote debugger.  I click yes, but then the breakpoint becomes an open gray circle, and, if I refresh the webpage, debugging doesn't occur.

Here is the print out from xdebug_info().  Debugger = Not Active seems wrong, but I don't know what to do with that if it is actually something wrong.

```
Version     3.1.5
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✘ disabled  
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Optional Features
Compressed File Support     yes (gzip)
Clock Source    GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
Diagnostic Log
No messages
Step Debugging  Docs
Debugger    Not Active  
PHP
Build Configuration
Version (Run Time)  8.0.11
Version (Compile Time)  8.0.19
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   disabled
Settings
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   no value
Loaded Configuration File   D:\winnmp\conf\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
Directive   Local Value Master Value    Docs
xdebug.mode debug   debug   
xdebug.start_with_request   default default 
xdebug.start_upon_error default default 
xdebug.output_dir   C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp 
xdebug.use_compression  1   1   
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value    
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value    
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value    
xdebug.log  no value    no value    
xdebug.log_level    7   7   
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3   
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256 
xdebug.cli_color    0   0   
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off 
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0   
xdebug.halt_level   0   0   
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1  
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value    
xdebug.dump_globals On  On  
xdebug.dump_once    On  On  
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p   
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off 
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value    
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost   
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003    
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off 
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value    
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value    
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200 
xdebug.scream   Off Off 
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p  
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c    
xdebug.trace_format 0   0   
xdebug.trace_options    0   0   
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
```

Comment: 1) Your 2nd half of the question -- that's about some JavaScript debug and not PHP debug anymore. It is not relevant to PHP debug. The thing is: it does not matter AT ALL what browser is used for PHP debug as PHP is a backend (web server) and not frontend (browser). The max that you need is Xdebug browser extension -- it will set Xdebug cookie that acts as "debug me" flag. That's it. The rest is your VSCode and PHP (Xdebug) config.

Comment: 2) Your Xdebug php.ini content -- that may not be enough. Xdebug may still not be able to see (or act when it sees) the "debug me" flag (Xdebug cookie or GET/POST param). Will it work if you add `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` there (this tells to try to debug every single request regardless of the "debug me" flag presence.

Comment: 3) If still nothing -- post the whole content of the `xdebug_info();` output captured via browser. It will show your live config and any troubleshooting messages that Xdebug may be printing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: Just in case: some old question/answer when Xdebug v3 was still a new thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141934/783119 . I may say that your "Listen for Xdebug" config is the same as I have here and it works (as long as the webserver and project root are the same path so no extra path mapping is needed). The rest -- Xdebug config in php.ini.

Comment: @LazyOne: Adding "xdebug.start_with_request = yes" had an odd effect of preventing the web page from completely loading (the reload button never appeared), but it didn't cause execution to stop a the breakpoint.  One very interesting, to me, fact from xdebug.info() is, under "Setp Debugging", it says "Debugger: Not Active".  What??  But I don't know enough to know what to do with that.  Here's the whole xdebug.info() print out.  BTW, my php error log has nothing about xdebug (after I removed "xdebug.start_with_request = yes" (to which said 3 different xdebug values were renamed).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! (in a way).  I don't know why my XDebug configuration wouldn't work with PHP 8, but I was able to retrieve a configuration (thanks to recent cloud versioning backup software I installed) using PHP 7.4.  So here are the settings that give me glorious step debugging in VSCode by refreshing the page in any browser.  I'm going to experiment and see if I can make this apply to PHP 8, but for now all is good.  I checked the php_xdebug.dll I had with file compare software and verified that it is the one listed here.

XDebug DLL:

```
php_xdebug-3.1.5-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
```

Php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

Launch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        }
       
    ]
}
```

Installed VS Code Extensions (if it matters):

```
Bookmarks, Live SAAS Compiler, Local History, PHP Debug, Prettier-Code formatter, Rainbow Brackets, Trailing Spaces.
```

Settings.json (if it matters):

```
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini and launch.json settings noted above **do work** with PHP 8 (8.0.11) and the XDebug.dll:

```
php_xdebug-3.1.5-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll
```

Note that the *instructions* provided at https://xdebug.org/wizard say:

```
Update D:\winnmp\conf\php.ini to have the line:
zend_extension = xdebug
```

This is quite different from the lines that were needed in my installation (WinNMP-- https://winnmp.wtriple.com/) in order to have success.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working in my case because i have to change ports from default 9003.
So, First i change my port in launch.json file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 11011
        },
```

In php.ini file

```
zend_extension = xdebug //Remember this is your file name which you downloaded
xdebug.mode = debug,develop
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.log_level = 0
xdebug.log = "C:\WINDOWS\temp\log.txt"
xdebug.client_port = 11011
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

Don't forget to restart your server and verify all these configurations in your browser by `phpinfo()`.